# How to read multiple times user input by ansible plabooks

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook to create a user if it does not exist. If it exist then it ask again for a new username. It must ask again for new user input. But var_promt runs only one time. How can I do that?

```
- name: An example prompting playbook
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "Enter a username"
  tasks:
    - name: Print out your input
      debug:
        msg: "You provided the {{ username }} for the  prompt"
    - name: User Exist
      command: grep {{ username }} /etc/passwd
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: user_exist
    - name: User Existance output
      debug: var=user_exist.stdout
    - name: User creation
      user: name={{ username }}
      when: user_exist.stdout is not match(".*:.*:.*:.*::.*:")
    - name: Display Message
      debug:
        msg: "User {{ username }} already exists"
      when: user_exist.stdout is match(".*:.*:.*:.*::.*:")
    - name: User check
      command: id {{ username }}
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: ID
    - name: UserID of Username
      debug: var=ID.stdout
```

Comment: Let's clarify the control flow first. Do you really want to manually enter the new "*user*" for "*all*" hosts where the "*username*" exists?

Comment: You shouldn't prompt for usernames. You should create a variable with a list of users and use `with_items` to make sure all users exist.

Comment: Dear Vlaimir and Garrett, I have solved the problem by making a list users. Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

- name: An example prompting playbook
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:

  - /root/users.yml
    tasks:
  - name: Create deploy user
    user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('password', '/tmp/{{ item.name }}.txt chars=ascii_letters') | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    createhome: yes
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    update_password: on_create
    with_items: "{{ users }}"

Comment: I have a problem. I want to run many commands within this loop (within with_items) but when I add other commands or modules, it gives an error ( ERROR! conflicting action statements: command, user
). What should I do to add more tasks in it.